# Unable to prepare route after upgrading from Laravel 6 to 8

Tags: routes, laravel-8

I just upgraded from Laravel 6 to 8 and now I am getting the following error when running php artisan optimize:

```
Unable to prepare route [post] for serialization. Another route has already been assigned name [post.index].
```

Here is what my web.php file looks like:

```
$Routes = function() {
    Route::get('/about', 'SinglePageController@about');
    Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');

    Route::resource('/post', 'PostController');
};


Route::group(['middleware' => 'impersonate','domain' => '127.0.0.1'], $Routes);
Route::group(['middleware' => 'impersonate','domain' => '127.0.0.2'], $Routes);
```

If I comment out the Route::resource or one of the Route::group lines it works with the limited functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the best solution, but the following routes worked.

```
Route::middleware(['impersonate'])->domain('127.0.11.1')->name('admin.')->group($Routes);
Route::middleware(['impersonate'])->domain('127.0.11.2')->name('viewer.')->group($Routes);
```